# How do I set up Line Out/In and Mic ports for surround sound?

Tags: sound, realtek, sony

I am running Ubuntu 12.10 on a Sony Vaio  VGC-RB34G ( http://reviews.cnet.com/desktops/sony-vaio-vgc-rb34g/4505-3118_7-31289053.html ) with an integrated Realtek High Definition Audio sound card. On Windows, I can set up the sound card to provide sound to my surround sound system from the Line Out, Line In, and Mic ports, as in all of these are producing audio.

I have tried to use alsa to achieve this result with no luck. Is there any possible way to do this on Ubuntu? Thanks!

Here is a Picture of the manager I have on Windows and the result I want to achieve:

[image]